# Media Query for Full HD mobile Dispalay

Tags: css, html, media-queries

How do i code a CSS media query for a Mobile Display that have a Full HD Display.
The way i'm doing is wrong and it displays a full desktop page on the display.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.container{
 width: 100%;
}
.buttons{
width:  95%;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
margin-top: 50%;

}
.blog{
width: 40%;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #ccc;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 25px;
background-color: #F9690E;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
}
.website{
width: 40%;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #ccc;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 25px;
background-color: #22A7F0;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
.container{
 width: 100%;
}
.buttons{
width:  95%;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
margin-top: 50%;

}
.blog{
width: 40%;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #ccc;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #F9690E;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
}
.website{
width: 40%;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #ccc;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #22A7F0;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}
}
```

Sorry for the poor indentation. If you can provide a JSFiddle it would be great.

Comment: Setting your max-width to 320px is not a good idea. Max-width will show on any screen that size or smaller, most mobiles these days are wider than that, and if the screen is landscape it will always be wider. A commonly used value is 768px

Comment: first we can't provide jsfiddle as there is no html..second, media queries are not like for hd but they are related to screen resoultion..show us any working demo or live link then we sure will help you..